# Would matrices of the same size be equal upon multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Here's the real question. P, Q, and R are matrices. Would P = Q if PR = QR?

Comment: Hint: does this hold for ordinary numbers (i.e. 1x1-matrices) $p, q, r$?

Comment: any square matrices

Comment: What @MeesdeVries is trying to say is this: If you expect it to be true for all square matrices, then at the very least it should be true for $1\times 1$ matrices (which are commonly known as "numbers"). You can just check yourself: Is it true for numbers?

Answer (score 3):

If $R=0$, then $PR=QR=0$, but in general $P \ne Q$.

Answer (score 1):

$PR=QR$ implies $P=Q$ only if $R$ is non-singular.

If $R$ is singular, the left null space (or cokernel) of $R$ will be non trivial, i.e. there will be $x$ such that $x^T R=0$ (and $x\not =0$). You can add such an $x^T$ to any row of, say, $P$ and the product with $R$ will obviously stay the same.